# Computing the asymptotics of a principal value integral

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function, cauchy-principal-value

I have been looking at the following principal value integral (with $x>0$ and $0< \sigma < 1$)

$$
\mathrm{P.V.} \int_0^\infty \frac{v^{-\sigma} e^{-x v}}{1 - v} dv,
$$

and I would like to know how to expand this integral for small values of $x$.

One option is to go through special functions and by inspection, [it looks like incomplete Gamma functions can be used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Connection_with_Kummer%27s_confluent_hypergeometric_function). This is confirmed by Mathematica, which can evaluate it to be

$$
\mathrm{P.V.} \int_0^\infty \frac{v^{-\sigma} e^{-x v}}{1 - v} dv = e^{-x}(-i\pi + e^{-i \pi \sigma} \sigma \Gamma(-\sigma) \Gamma(\sigma, -x)),
$$

and it has the expansion

$$
\mathrm{P.V.} \int_0^\infty \frac{v^{-\sigma} e^{-x v}}{1 - v} dv = -\pi \cot(\pi\sigma)(1 - x + O(x^2))  - \Gamma(-\sigma)x^{\sigma} \left(1 - \tfrac1{1+\sigma} x + O(x^2)\right),
$$

However, my question is specifically: How do I derive either of the above two equalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with [$(8.6.4)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.6.E4):
$$\tag{1}
\Gamma (\sigma ,z) = \frac{{z^\sigma  e^{ - z} }}{{\Gamma (1 - \sigma )}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^{ - \sigma } e^{ - t} }}{{z + t}}dt} 
$$
valid for $|\arg z|<\pi$ and $\Re\sigma<1$. Using [$(8.2.10)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2.E10), we find
$$
\Gamma (\sigma ,z) =  - \frac{{2\pi i}}{{\Gamma (1 - \sigma )}}e^{\pi i\sigma }  + e^{2\pi i\sigma } \Gamma (\sigma ,ze^{ - 2\pi i} ).
$$
Hence
$$\tag{2}
\Gamma (\sigma ,z) =  - \frac{{2\pi i}}{{\Gamma (1 - \sigma )}}e^{\pi i\sigma }  + \frac{{z^\sigma  e^{ - z} }}{{\Gamma (1 - \sigma )}}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^{ - \sigma } e^{ - t} }}{{z + t}}dt} 
$$
provided $\pi  < \arg z < 3\pi$ and $\Re\sigma<1$. Approaching $z = xe^{\pi i}$, $x>0$, in $(1)$ and $(2)$ and taking the average of the two expressions, we find
$$
\Gamma (\sigma , - x) =  - \frac{{\pi i}}{{\Gamma (1 - \sigma )}}e^{\pi i\sigma }  + e^{\pi i\sigma } \frac{{x^\sigma  e^x }}{{\Gamma (1 - \sigma )}}{\rm P}{\rm .V}{\rm .}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{t^{ - \sigma } e^{ - t} }}{{ - x + t}}dt} ,
$$
or with $t=vx$,
$$
\Gamma (\sigma , - x) =  - \frac{{\pi i}}{{\Gamma (1 - \sigma )}}e^{\pi i\sigma }  - e^{\pi i\sigma } \frac{{e^x }}{{\Gamma (1 - \sigma )}}{\rm P}{\rm .V}{\rm .}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{v^{ - \sigma } e^{ - xv} }}{{1 - v}}dv} .
$$
Rearranging yields
\begin{align*}
{\rm P}{\rm .V}{\rm .}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{v^{ - \sigma } e^{ - xv} }}{{1 - v}}dv} & = e^{ - x} ( - \pi i - e^{ - \pi i\sigma } \Gamma (1 - \sigma )\Gamma (\sigma , - x)) \\ & = e^{ - x} ( - \pi i + e^{ - \pi i\sigma } \sigma \Gamma (\sigma )\Gamma (\sigma , - x)).
\end{align*}
Now just apply [$(8.7.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.7.E3) and the Maclaurin series of $e^{-x}$ to get the desired power series about $0$.

Comment: Great, thanks! Two little things: (1) An assumed step that might confuse readers: How taking the average leads to only getting the principal value ($\frac{1}{x\pm i\delta} = \mathrm{P.V.}\frac1x \mp i \pi \delta(x)$ kinda of argument). And (2) I realize it's ambiguous which "sheet" we take for $\Gamma(\sigma, -x)$ [(8.6.9)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.6#E9); it seems like it's chosen to be just below the branch cut on the negative axis.

Comment: @qgp07 To be honest, I chose the sheet to end up with the result given by Mathematica. I should have scrolled down to $(8.6.9)$ to arrive at the result faster.